# Search geo_point Location by latitude and longitude - Java Query

Tags: java, geolocation, elasticsearch

Trying a Java query to search Locations by latitude/longitude pair:

(Locations is indexed as `geo_point`, with `lat_lon` set to true)

```
SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch("index1").setTypes("pin").setQuery((filteredQuery(matchAllQuery(), geoDistanceFilter("location").distance("1km").point(latitude, longitude)))).execute().actionGet();
```

This query works Ok, however it requires specifying a "distance" in the filter, Locations in my index should be unique, 
and so I 'm looking into another option to construct a query given only latitude & longitude as inputs, and the result being one or none.

I was wondering if specifying a distance may yields more than a single point.

Comment: Can't comment on the java interface but using geopoint with a distance filter can definitely return multple results -- we use it to find places witing X km of a point. (obviously). On your point about unique locations and being able to find a place with the exact lat lon - that sounds like an impossible use case - why would you look in a search engine if you allready knew the details of the document you were wanting? presumably if you know the *exact* latitude and longitude then you must know something else about the document allready?